# NSString value overlays others when displayed in UITextView parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

If I change titleTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] to any other colour it displays what I need, but if I leave it like it is, is overlays all the [object objectForKey:@"imageTitle"] values.

Has anyone encountered such an issue? Any suggestions?

Here is what i am doing right now.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

NSUInteger index = [self indexForObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    // Header
    return [self detailPhotoCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    // Photo
    PhotoViewCell *cell = (PhotoViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PhotoViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.photoButton.tag = index;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderPhoto.png"];

    if (object) {


        UITextView * titleTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.imageView.bounds.size.width/2, cell.imageView.bounds.size.width, cell.imageView.bounds.size.width)];

        cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];



        titleTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleTextView.text = [object objectForKey:@"imageTitle"];
        titleTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:30];
        titleTextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: titleTextView];


        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"footerCell";

        PhotoFooterView *footerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!footerView) {
            footerView = [[PhotoFooterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, cell.imageView.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f) buttons:PhotoFooterButtonsDefault];
            footerView.delegate = self;




        }
        PFObject *object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        footerView.photo = object;
        footerView.tag = index;
        [footerView.likeButton setTag:index];

        NSDictionary *attributesForPhoto = [[APPCache sharedCache] attributesForPhoto:object];

        if (attributesForPhoto) {
            [footerView setLikeStatus:[[APPCache sharedCache] isPhotoLikedByCurrentUser:object]];
            [footerView.likeButton setTitle:[[[APPCache sharedCache] likeCountForPhoto:object] description] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [footerView.commentButton setTitle:[[[APPCache sharedCache] commentCountForPhoto:object] description] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            if (footerView.likeButton.alpha < 1.0f || footerView.commentButton.alpha < 1.0f) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.200f animations:^{
                    footerView.likeButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                    footerView.commentButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                }];
            }
        } else {
            footerView.likeButton.alpha = 0.0f;
            footerView.commentButton.alpha = 0.0f;

            @synchronized(self) {
                // check if we can update the cache
                NSNumber *outstandingSectionHeaderQueryStatus = [self.outstandingSectionHeaderQueries objectForKey:@(index)];
                if (!outstandingSectionHeaderQueryStatus) {
                    PFQuery *query = [AAPUtility queryForActivitiesOnPhoto:object cachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];
                    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                        @synchronized(self) {
                            [self.outstandingSectionHeaderQueries removeObjectForKey:@(index)];

                            if (error) {
                                return;
                            }

                            NSMutableArray *likers = [NSMutableArray array];
                            NSMutableArray *commenters = [NSMutableArray array];

                            BOOL isLikedByCurrentUser = NO;

                            for (PFObject *activity in objects) {
                                if ([[activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey] isEqualToString:kPAPActivityTypeLike] && [activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey]) {
                                    [likers addObject:[activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey]];
                                } else if ([[activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey] isEqualToString:kPAPActivityTypeComment] && [activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey]) {
                                    [commenters addObject:[activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey]];
                                }

                                if ([[[activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey] objectId] isEqualToString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]]) {
                                    if ([[activity objectForKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey] isEqualToString:kPAPActivityTypeLike]) {
                                        isLikedByCurrentUser = YES;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            [[APPCache sharedCache] setAttributesForPhoto:object likers:likers commenters:commenters likedByCurrentUser:isLikedByCurrentUser];

                            if (footerView.tag != index) {
                                return;
                            }

                            [footerView setLikeStatus:[[APPCache sharedCache] isPhotoLikedByCurrentUser:object]];
                            [footerView.likeButton setTitle:[[[APPCache sharedCache] likeCountForPhoto:object] description] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [footerView.commentButton setTitle:[[[APPCache sharedCache] commentCountForPhoto:object] description] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                            if (footerView.likeButton.alpha < 1.0f || footerView.commentButton.alpha < 1.0f) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.200f animations:^{
                                    footerView.likeButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                                    footerView.commentButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                                }];
                            }
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }
        }

        [cell addSubview:footerView];

        // PFQTVC will take care of asynchronously downloading files, but will only load them when the tableview is not moving. If the data is there, let's load it right away.
        if ([cell.imageView.file isDataAvailable]) {
            [cell.imageView loadInBackground];
        }
      }
    return cell;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `UITableView` cells are reused.  When a cell scrolls off the edge of the table, the "new" cell that replaces it on the other side is actually the same object (providing dramatic savings in view creation and destruction).

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns one of those cells, most of the time reused from a scrolled-away position.  Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` adds a text view *every time*, which means most of the time it is piling text view upon text view.  The clear color background allows you to notice the mistake.

The fix is to build the text view conditionally, only if the cell doesn't have one already, like this...

```
    // your existing code up to here

    UITextView *titleTextView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:99];
    // this condition guards against building another text view when you have one already
    if (!textView) {
        titleTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: // and so on
        // so we can find it later in the viewWithTag line above
        titleTextView.tag = 99;
        // your code to build the text view here, but not the line
        // that sets the text.  we do that unconditionally for every cell
        [cell.contentView addSubview: titleTextView];
    }
    // this part of the view varies by cell, so do it unconditionally...
    titleTextView.text = [object objectForKey:@"imageTitle"];

    // your existing code from here
```

As an aside, the remainder of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is long and non-standard, two warning signs of troubles ahead.  I'm especially puzzled by the second call to dequeue for a "footerView".

And it is definitely ill-advised to launch asynch calls in this method without first checking if you've already fetched the data.  Remember, this method gets called over and over rapidly as the user scrolls over the same cells.  For the same reason you only build a single text view per cell, you need a guard to insure a single request (or fewer) per cell.

Step one to fix this is to move all of that model-related code out of the datasource method.  Have your model cache results, and return the completion right away if the result has already been fetched.

Comment: thank you @danh , it worked like a charm and thanks for all the suggestions, will take care of the "footerView" as well